Redis read Performance issue using Lettuce with WebFlux
I was trying check the performance of reading Redis data using WebFlux. What I found is since the WebFlux is using single thread to perform the read and deserialize the response (e.g lettuce-ioEventLoop-5-1). The main time consumed in doing the deserialization of the response using WebFlux (which won't allow you to take advantage of multiple core).
As per the lettuce documentation it is suggesting to use ClientOptions but I don't know how to use it in below code.
https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#faq.reactive-single-connection
My code looks pretty simple as shown below
@GetMapping(value = "/{testName}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Test> getTest(@PathVariable String testName) {
    return testService.getCachedTest(testName)
            .log();
}

The RedisConfig looks like below
    @Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Test> redisOperations(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory) {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Test> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Test.class);

        RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Test> builder =
                RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Test.class));

        RedisSerializationContext<String, Test> context =
                builder
                        .key(new StringRedisSerializer())
                        .value(serializer)
                        .build();

        return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory, context);
    }
}

Can anyone please help to configure the ClientOptions or need to do a trick here?
Update
Found a way to configure the ClientOptions. It helps to improve the performance drastically (in case of machine having multiple cores). As a result I can still see the VT is outperforming the webflux
public class RedisConfig {

@Bean
public ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Pokemon> redisOperations(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory) {
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Pokemon> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Pokemon.class);

    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Pokemon> builder =
            RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Pokemon.class));

    RedisSerializationContext<String, Pokemon> context =
            builder
                    .key(new StringRedisSerializer())
                    .value(serializer)
                    .build();

    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory, context);
}

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
    ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
            .publishOnScheduler(true)
            .build();
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .clientOptions(clientOptions)
            .build();
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfiguration);
}

}
Before ClientOptions configuration in webflux
"http.response_time": {
    "min": 2,
    "max": 33,
    "count": 8330,
    "mean": 8.4,
    "p50": 6,
    "median": 6,
    "p75": 12.1,
    "p90": 16.9,
    "p95": 19.1,
    "p99": 22.9,
    "p999": 27.9
  }

After ClientOptions configuration in webflux
"http.response_time": {
    "min": 3,
    "max": 47,
    "count": 8330,
    "mean": 4.7,
    "p50": 4,
    "median": 4,
    "p75": 5,
    "p90": 6,
    "p95": 7,
    "p99": 8.9,
    "p999": 19.9
  }


I'd suggest to look at the general config for the WebFlux app, you have something misconfigured most likely

There is no configuration. The app is simple doesn't have any configuration. Everything is default and using JDK 21
